# Rewrite Embedded Property to Top Level Field for All Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have structure that look more or less like this:

```
{
   "_id": "xxx",
   "pubDate": {
     "dateTime": ISODate("2018-05-09T10:00:45.0Z"),
     "offset": "Z",
     "zone": "Z"
  }
}
```

How can I change `pubDate.dateTime` within the nested object to just `pubDate`

```
{
   "_id": "xxx",
   "pubDate": ISODate("2018-05-09T10:00:45.0Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) with two steps and the [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) update modifier:

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { },
    "update": {
      "$rename": { "pubDate.dateTime": "tmpDate" }
    }
  }},
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { },
    "update": {
      "$rename": { "tmpDate": "pubDate" }
    }
  }}
])
```

That's the fastest way to rewrite all fields like this. You need two steps because you cannot just write up one level to `pubDate` as a property when something already exists inside it.

Comment: I got this error ```TypeError: Property 'bulkWrite' of object xxx.collection is not a function```

Comment: @MAGx2 Which version of MongoDB are you using? `bulkWrite()` has been around for a long time. If you're using any version less than 3.0 then upgrading should be a priority. You did change `collection` to you actual collection name I hope? Also where are you running this? That does not look like a `mongo` shell error, and there should be no need to run this code anywhere else since it only ever needs to be run "once"

Comment: I got this. On my dev env (vagrant) I have old mongo. My staging is working on ```3.6.4```. I have one more think to ask you - please look into updated question

Comment: @MAGx2 If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Changing your question after it is answered is not acceptable. Note that your concept is wrong anyway. It's not MongoDB storing things differently but your application.

Comment: @MAGx2 That has nothing to do with the answer here.